# Convert series to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

I am having dataset on which I applied the groupby function

```
data.groupby(by=['version','sentiment']).score.count()
```

the output is:

```
version  sentiment       
10.1.2   negative        3.0
         positive        8.0
10.2.0   negative        1.0
10.4.2   negative        1.0
10.4.3   negative        1.0
10.4.6   positive        1.0
10.5.1   negative        1.0
10.5.2   positive        1.0
10.5.5   negative        2.0
11.0     negative        1.0
11.2     negative        3.0
         positive        1.0
11.3.1   negative        1.0
```

No i want to convert this in dictionary form where the output should be something like:

```
{'10.1.2' : {
      'positive' : 3,
      'negative' : 8
},
'10.2.0' : {
}
```

Comment: is this a Series?

Comment: yes , this is series,
output of :
data.groupby(by=['version','sentiment']).score.count()
indexed on version & sentiment

Comment: tell me if my solution works

Comment: I am glad to help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need:

```
s.unstack().to_dict('index')
#.unstack(level = 0).to_dict()
```

**where s is your serie**

```
data.groupby(by=['version','sentiment']).score.count().unstack().to_dict()
```

---

**I have used a DataFrame to solve your problem**

```
print(df)
        i1        i2  col
0   10.1.2  negative  3.0
1   10.1.2  positive  8.0
2   10.2.0  negative  1.0
3   10.4.2  negative  1.0
4   10.4.3  negative  1.0
5   10.4.6  positive  1.0
6   10.5.1  negative  1.0
7   10.5.2  positive  1.0
8   10.5.5  negative  2.0
9     11.0  negative  1.0
10    11.2  negative  3.0
11    11.2  positive  1.0
12  11.3.1  negative  1.0


df.set_index(['i1','i2'])['col'].unstack().to_dict('index')
#{'10.1.2': {'negative': 3.0, 'positive': 8.0},
# '10.2.0': {'negative': 1.0, 'positive': nan},
# '10.4.2': {'negative': 1.0, 'positive': nan},
# '10.4.3': {'negative': 1.0, 'positive': nan},
# '10.4.6': {'negative': nan, 'positive': 1.0},
# '10.5.1': {'negative': 1.0, 'positive': nan},
# '10.5.2': {'negative': nan, 'positive': 1.0},
# '10.5.5': {'negative': 2.0, 'positive': nan},
# '11.0': {'negative': 1.0, 'positive': nan},
# '11.2': {'negative': 3.0, 'positive': 1.0},
# '11.3.1': {'negative': 1.0, 'positive': nan}}
```